# How to make a component for modal box in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I want to make a component which generates any number of buttons passed to it.
Now, the questions is how to pass the data about the button from template to component, so that the specified action will get called on click of the corresponding button.

Comment: Passing properties and actions to component. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/ sample code will help to answer

Comment: Yeah, but how to make button without using {yield} in component. And if I send one button name and action, it must generate one, if two then two, and so on.

Comment: `each` helper will iterate and create button component

Comment: Thanks. If, for example, I have a component named modal-box. Then I write {{modal-box button="yes" action="save" button="no" action="cancel" }}. But how to get these property in component and use each helper, etc to iterate??

Comment: Yes. you can combine `each` helper and  `component` helper to render component runtime

Comment: Show some things you've tried. Check out ember-twiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass buttons as array. Here is an example of how to render them. In component's template:

```
{{#each buttons as |button|}}
    <button type="button"
            class="{{button.className}} button"
                onclick={{action button.action}}>
       {{button.text}}
    </button>
{{/each}}
```

Then, somewhere in template where you want to use your component:

```
{{your-component buttons=(array (className='green' text='Save' action=(action (mut variable) 'value')))}}
```

`array` helper is a part of [ember-composable-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers)